# how to install KeePassX 2.0 Alpha on ubuntu

Tags: security, tools, keepass

On the KeePassX site there is only a Linux version 0.4.3 for download.

how can I install the latest version on Ubuntu?

The problem is, that 
Version 0.4 is basically unmaintained.

see: 
https://www.keepassx.org/dev/issues/78#change-186

Comment: Related bug report: [Please update KeePassX to v2.0 Alpha](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1128151)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I didn't have any trouble building from source:

```
# Assuming you have basic build tools already installed
sudo apt-get install cmake libgcrypt11-dev
git clone https://github.com/keepassx/keepassx.git
cd keepassx/
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
make 2>&1 | tee make.log
sudo make install 2>&1 | tee make-install.log
```

Comment: do this first if you missing any libraries. - sudo apt-get build-dep keepassx - sudo apt-get install ubuntu-dev-tools cmake zlib1g-dev libgcrypt11-dev

Comment: This was one of the first open source projects I've ever been able to successfully build; After tens and tens of tries, finally a build system that actually works upon release.

Comment: after I've compiled it, can I completely delete the folder "keepassx"?

Answer (score 9):

In this Related bug report: [Please update KeePassX to v2.0 Alpha](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/keepassx/+bug/1128151)

The developer now offers a PPA with daily builds for those who would like to test it:
https://launchpad.net/~keepassx/+archive/daily

Answer (score 5):

Just to simplify things. To install from the repository robo77 mentioned:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:keepassx/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install keepassx
```